# word frequency calculation in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code, to count the frequency of word occurrences in a document containing about 20000 files,i am able to get the overall frequency of a word in the document and
my code so far is :

```
import os
import re
import sys
sys.stdout=open('f2.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob

def removegarbage(text):
    text=re.sub(r'\W+',' ',text)
    text=text.lower()
    return text

folderpath='d:/articles-words'
counter=Counter()

for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')):
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        counter.update(removegarbage(filehandle.read()).split())

for word,count in counter.most_common():
    print('{}  {}'.format(word,count))
```

But, i want to modify my counter, and update it only once for every file, that is count must correspond to either 0 or 1 for its occurrence or non occurrence in a file in the document.
for ex:
the word "little", occurs 3 times in file1, and 8 times in file45,
thereby, the count value must be 2 not 11
but my present code shows 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sets`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')):
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        words = set(removegarbage(filehandle.read()).split()) 
        counter.update(words)
```

A `set` contains only unique values:

```
>>> strs = "foo bat foo"
>>> set(strs.split())
set(['bat', 'foo'])
```

Example using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> strs = "foo bat foo"
>>> c.update(set(strs.split()))
>>> strs = "foo spam foo"
>>> c.update(set(strs.split()))
>>> c
Counter({'foo': 2, 'bat': 1, 'spam': 1})
```