# how to find word frequency without duplicates across multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the frequency of words in multiple files in a folder, i need to increment a word's count by 1 if it is found in a  file.
For ex:the line "all's well that ends well" if read in file 1 must increment the count of "well" by 1 and not 2,
and if "she is not well" is read in file2, the count of "well" shall become 2

i need to increment the counter without including the duplicates, but my program does not take that into account, so plz help!!

```
import os
import re
import sys
sys.stdout=open('f1.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob

def removegarbage(text):
    text=re.sub(r'\W+',' ',text)
    text=text.lower()
    sorted(text)
    return text

def removeduplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))


folderpath='d:/articles-words'
counter=Counter()


filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

num_files = len(filepaths)

# Add all words to counter
for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        lines = filehandle.read()
        words = removegarbage(lines).split()
        cwords=removeduplicates(words)
        counter.update(cwords)

# Display most common
for word, count in counter.most_common():

    # Break out if the frequency is less than 0.1 * the number of files
    if count < 0.1*num_files:
        break
    print('{}  {}'.format(word,count))
```

I have tried the sort and remove duplicate techniques, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: I think your friend beat you to it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137684/word-frequency-calculation-in-multiple-files

Comment: I'd build a set of words for each file, and as your find the EOF you update your dictionary of counters, incrementing for each entry in set.

Then start a new set for the next file.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: windows 7,and i am working on python 3.3

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? What is happening? What do you expect instead? Can you give some example input (say, two short files) and the output you're getting that is clearly incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, basically you want to know for each word, how many times does it appear across all files (regardless if the same word is more than once in a same file). 
In order to do this, I did the following schema, that simulates a list of many files (I just cared about the process, not the files per-se, so you might have to manage to change the "files" for the actual list you want to process.

```
d = {}
i = 0 
for f in files:
    i += 1
    for line in f:   
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in d:
                d[word] = {}
            d[word][i] = 1    

d2 = {}
for word,occurences in d.iteritems():
    d2[word] = sum( d[word].values() )
```

The result will give you something like the following:
{'ends': 1, 'that': 1, 'is': 1, 'well': 2, 'she': 1, 'not': 1, "all's": 1}

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it a much different way, but the crux of it is using a set.

```
frequency = Counter()
for line in open("file", "r"):
    for word in set(line):
        frequency[word] += 1
```

I'm not sure if it's preferable to use `.readline()` or whatnot; I typically use for loops because they're so damn simple.

*Edit*: I see what you're doing wrong. You read the entire contents of the file with `.read()`, (perform `removegarbage()` on it) and then `.split()` the result. That'll give you a single list, destroying the newlines:

```
>>> "Hello world!\nFoo bar!".split()
['Hello', 'world!', 'Foo', 'bar!']
```